# storing Mousebutton events in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to click with the mouse on to different rectangle buttons in Pygame,getting the x-y position and make an if statement with them as variables.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    .
    .
    .


if button_cliked_one and button_cliked_two:
    print ('buttons clicked')

else:
    print('something is wrong')
```

Comment: yes, you can (if I only understand what you try to say). what did you try ? what error did you get ?

Comment: BTW: if you have event `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` then you can get mouse position from `event.pos`

Comment: I can only make one mouse event for a mouse button down and not for multiple. How is this possible

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. Do you want to catch two mouse buttons click (left + right) ? You have `event.button` ? Or you want to catch double-click ? You can save one clik and current time. and later get second click and compare time with previous click.

Comment: I have a window 1200*800 pixel. In draw  2  buttons(buttons  A,B)and 4 other buttons(C,D,E,F). If I click on one  button(A) then the other four(C,D,E,F) has to vanish.Until now I  complished it. But when I must click button B, I want to click and a second button like F  to vanish the other three buttons(C,D,E).And there is the problem.I can't get two mouse clicks events stored in two variables and compare to each other with a "and" or an "or" operator.

Comment: i don't have the code only the above one. Of course I used collide point(mouse_x,mouse_y) function and stored the x and y coordinates in a variable like button_cliked_A.But now I need to store, two events in two variables like button_cliked_B and button_cliked_C and it does not storing that, because only once will store the mouse get.pos() into a variable

Comment: I don't understand why you can't keep event in variable and use it when you get next event.

Comment: both perfect thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand what you want, but maybe you want to store previous mouse clicking positions in order to draw rectangles?

All you have to do is to store then in a different variable. If you want just two click positions at a time, you just use that. Or you can use a Python list to store the positions of an arbitrary number of clicks.

```
import pygame, sys

SIZE = 640, 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

# empty list
all_clicks = []

drawn = True
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # store mouse click position in the list:
            all_clicks.append(event.pos)
            # event.pos already has the info you'd get by calling pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            drawn = False
            print(all_clicks)

    # at every second click:
    if not len(all_clicks) % 2 and not drawn:
        # draw a rectangle having the click positions as coordinates:
        # pick the minimal x coordinate of both clicks as left position for rect:
        x = min(all_clicks[-1][0], all_clicks[-2][0])
        # ditto for top positionn
        y = min(all_clicks[-1][1], all_clicks[-2][1])
        # and calculate width and height in the same way
        w = max(all_clicks[-1][0], all_clicks[-2][0]) - x
        h = max(all_clicks[-1][1], all_clicks[-2][1]) - y
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, w, h))
        drawn = True

    # update screen:
    pygame.display.flip()
    # pause a while (30ms) least our game use 100% cpu for nothing:
    pygame.time.wait(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables `previous_button` and `current_button` to remeber two last buttons. And then you can check if they are correct.

It is similar to @jsbueno solution but I use two variables, not list. 
If you want check longer combinations then you can use list.

```
import pygame

# --- functions ---

def check_which_button_was_click(buttons, pos):

    for name, (rect, color) in buttons.items():
        if rect.collidepoint(pos):
            return name

# --- main ---

# - init -

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((350, 150))

# - objects -

buttons = {
    'RED':   (pygame.Rect(50, 50, 50, 50),  (255, 0, 0)),
    'GREEN': (pygame.Rect(150, 50, 50, 50), (0, 255, 0)),
    'BLUE':  (pygame.Rect(250, 50, 50, 50), (0, 0, 255)),
}

previous_button = None
current_button = None

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    # - event -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            clicked_button = check_which_button_was_click(buttons, event.pos)
            if clicked_button is not None:
               previous_button = current_button
               current_button = clicked_button
            print(previous_button, current_button)

    # - updates -

    if previous_button == 'RED' and current_button == 'BLUE':
        print('correct buttons clicked: RED & BLUE')
        previous_button = None
        current_button = None

    # - draws -

    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    for rect, color in buttons.values():
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(5)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```